# Cython function number precicion

Tags: python-2.7, cython

I have the following function and run it under 64Bit:

```
from math import log, e    #natürlicher Logarithmus
from scipy.special import ndtr
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np  

cdef float callPrice(float underlyingPrice,float strikePrice,float interestRate,float daysToExpiration, float volatility):
    volatility = volatility / 100

    cdef float a,d1,d2,call    

    if volatility == 0 or daysToExpiration == 0:
        call = max(0.0, underlyingPrice - strikePrice)
    if strikePrice == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError('The strike price cannot be zero')
    else:
        a = volatility * daysToExpiration**0.5
        d1 = (log(underlyingPrice / strikePrice) + (interestRate + (volatility**2) / 2) * daysToExpiration) / a
        d2 = d1 - a
        #call = underlyingPrice * norm.cdf(d1) - strikePrice * e**(interestRate * daysToExpiration) * norm.cdf(d2)         
        call = underlyingPrice * ndtr(d1) - strikePrice * e**(interestRate * daysToExpiration) * ndtr(d2) 
        print "call: ", call, "stock: ", underlyingPrice, "daystoexpiry: " ,  daysToExpiration, "vola: ", "interest rate: ", interestRate, "strike: ", strikePrice , volatility
    return call
```

Function inputs are:

underlyingPrice:  5047.0 
daysToExpiration:  0.597260296345 
volatility: 0.352554321289 
interestRate:  0.0299999993294 
strikePrice:  4600.0

function output call is 724.487365723.
When I do this calculation in Excel or in some online calculator, output is 823.7. Thats a huge difference, reason so far is unclear to me. Why is that?

Comment: do you see the same problem when you switch to double?

Comment: add `print` statements in your code, and see where it fails compared to your excel calculation. Moreover on my machine a pure python implementation (getting rid of the `float` here and there basically) leads to `363.8` as result. And it is usually much better/faster to prototype the function in ipython until it works, and then `cythonize` it at a later stage if needed